# I will always support you

Tags: vocabulary

I've always been confused with the translation of "always" and "never".

My thoughts on the above phrase would be either:

我永远会支持你。

我一直都会支持你。

Which if any is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do that like this:

我永远会支持你。
I will always support you.

或者

我会一直支持你。
I will always support you.

Answer (score 1):

always - 一直；永远

never - 永不；绝不

我永远都会支持你。= 我一直都会支持你。- I'll always support you.

我永远都不会支持你。= 我绝不会支持你。- I'll never support you.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of "always" is "never".

"always" means at all times, perpetually.
"never" means at no time and on no occasion.

"我永远会支持你。" is equal to "我一直都会支持你。".
Both can be translated to "I will always support you."

Answer (score 1):

always - 永远，一直

never - 永远不，一直不

not always - 不永远，不一直

I will always support you. = 我会永远支持你。/我会一直支持你。

I will never support you. = 我永远不会支持你。/我绝不支持你。

I will not always support you. = 我不会永远支持你。/我有时候支持你，有时候不支持你。